# Logitech camera C310 doesn't work on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, camera, logitech

Logitech camera C310 doesn't work on Raspberry Pi 3, after doing `cap = VideoCapture(0, CAP_DSHOW)` and then doing `_, frame = cap.read()` and then running the code I get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'`. Why? The camera works fine on my PC so I don't understand why it gives me error on Raspberry.

```
cap = VideoCapture(0, CAP_DSHOW)
while 1:
     _, frame = cap.read()
     f = frame.copy()
```

Comment: please post the whole code and stacktrace, it's not clear where `frame` attribute is accessed

Comment: also, `_, frame` first item is response result, you should validate if it's True before working with the frame

Comment: @Antigluk the code is the same exact code I tested on a LattePanda and it doesn't give me any errors on the LattePanda so it's a Raspberry problem but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: still, it would be hard to help if you don't post it :) and the traceback

Comment: @Antigluk unfortunately I dont' have the traceback with me now but I can post it as soon as I get it. I posted the relevant part of the code, but still I don't think it's a code problem. Maybe the Raspberry needs the camera drivers?

Comment: can you try to make a photo with camera using some 3rd party app from the repo? like Cheese

Comment: @Antigluk yes, I've tried that and the camera is not detected

Comment: then I think you're right, you need a driver

Comment: @Antigluk I've been searching but I don't know where to find it

Comment: does your system even see it? check with `lsusb -v`

Comment: @Antigluk I tried that and it says 'Logitech' in a line so I guess it sees it